# object was not found in R

Tags: r

i used following tutorial for learning R programming language
[R programming language](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_repeat_loop.htm)

```
v <- c("Hello","loop")
cnt <- 2

repeat {
  print(v)
  cnt <- cnt+1

  if(cnt > 5) {
    break
  }
}
```

but when i run this code, it gave me the following error

```
> if(cnt > 5) {
+     break
+   }
Error: object 'cnt' not found
>
```

this example was taken from tutorial itself, what is    wrong  in  given code?

Comment: I get "Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level" which makes sense since this code chunk doesn't make sense outside of a loop environment.  Did you clear your environment/restart R before running the second chunk?

Comment: i have restarted  again and now  got  following error  Error in print(v) : object 'v' not found

Comment: variables aren't persistent between R sessions unless you save and reload your environment.  You need to run *all of the lines in the code chunk*.

Comment: how can i do   this one  ?could you show me with example?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish @datodatuashvili?

Comment: i just started to learn R programming language and  i am learning  basics

Comment: I assume there are several things going wrong. 
First to make surem there's no other `v` or `cnt` in our enviroment, use `rm(v, cnt)`. If you get a warning that there are no such variables, you can ignore it. 
Then you should run the first part if your exercise, where `v`and `cnt` are assigned. 
After that you should run erverything from **repeat** to the last durly bracket. If you only run the part about  `if(cnt > 5)` R doesn't know what to break.

Comment: if i will put everything in function body?

Comment: @kath thanks  very much, very strange property  compare to matlab,   matlab does not have such issues